# Java Socket programming: Client receives " " instead of id

Tags: java, sockets, bufferedreader, printwriter

I'm writing a simple chat program using sockets. The program works as clients connect to the server and before they start chatting, they send their name to the server and receive an unique id on the return. This is where my code doesn't work properly.

Here's my code in `Client` class which sends name and receives id:

```
private void exchangeInformation() {
        String temp;
        try {
            writer.println(name);
            temp = reader.readLine();
            System.out.println(temp);
            temp = reader.readLine();
            System.out.println("id has been received : "
                    + temp);
            this.id = Integer.parseInt(temp);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error Occured\n"
                    + "Message: Couldn't get id from server\n"
                    + "Cause: " + e.getMessage() + "\n");
        }
    }
```

---

And here's the code in server side which receives name and sends id:

```
private void exchangeInformation() {

        try {
            String n = reader.readLine();
            setUserName(n);
            System.out.println("name has been received");
            writeMessage("Server: Welcome " + userName + "\n");

            writeMessage(userId);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error Occured\n"
                    + "Message: Couldn't receive client's name\n"
                    + "Cause: " + e.getMessage() + "\n");
        }
    }
```

---

and this is `writeMessage` method on the server side:

```
public synchronized void writeMessage(String message) {
        writer.println(message);
    }
```

---

In both sides, `writer` is an object of `PrintWriter` and `reader` is an object of `BufferedReader`.

Well, the problem is, when I send `userId` to the client, client receives "" instead of proper data. the other parts of code work fine.

What is the problem and how can I fix it?

Regards

---

EDIT: As suggested in comments, All code:

`Client` class:

```
public class Client {

    private String name;
    private int id;
    private boolean isConnected;

    private BufferedReader reader;
    //private BufferedWriter writer;
    private PrintWriter writer;
    private Socket socket;

    public Client(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public boolean getIsConnected() {
        return isConnected;
    }

    public BufferedReader getReader() {
        return reader;
    }

    public void start() {

        connect();

        exchangeInformation();

        new ReceiveFromServer(this).start();

        String output;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (isConnected) {
            System.out.println("YOU: ");
            output = in.nextLine();
            writer.print(name + " : " + output);
        }

        try {
            socket.close();
            reader.close();
            writer.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error Occured\n"
                    + "Message: Couldn't close content(s)\n"
                    + "Cause: " + e.getMessage() + "\n");
        }
    }

    private void connect() {
        System.out.println("Trying to connect to the server...\n");
        try {
            socket = new Socket("localhost", 4444);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error Occured\n"
                    + "Message: User " + name + " couldn't connetct to the server\n"
                    + "Cause: " + e.getMessage() + "\n");
        }
        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            writer = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error Occured\n"
                    + "Message: Couldn't get socket's InputStream or OutputStream\n"
                    + "Cause: " + e.getMessage());
        }

        System.out.println("You have cnnected to the server successfully");
    }

    private void exchangeInformation() {
        String temp;
        try {
            writer.println(name);
            temp = reader.readLine();
            System.out.println(temp);
            temp = reader.readLine();
            System.out.println("id has been received : "
                    + temp);
            this.id = Integer.parseInt(temp);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error Occured\n"
                    + "Message: Couldn't get id from server\n"
                    + "Cause: " + e.getMessage() + "\n");
        }
    }
```

### }

`Server` class:

```
public class Server {

    private static Server server = new Server(4444);

    private final int PORT;
    private List<ClientThread> clients;
    private static int counter;

    private ServerSocket ss;
    private boolean isListening;

    private Server(int port) {
        this.PORT = port;
        clients = new ArrayList<>();
        counter = 0;
    }

    public static Server getServerInstance() {
        return server;
    }

    private int generateId() {
        return ++counter;
    }

    public void start() {
        establishConnection();

        while (isListening) {
            System.out.println("Server is Listening...");
            Socket s = null;
            try {
                s = ss.accept();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Error Occured\n"
                        + "Message: An error occured while accepting a request\n"
                        + "Cause: " + e.getMessage());
            }
            System.out.println("New connection request has been accepted\n");
            ClientThread client = new ClientThread(s, this.generateId());
            clients.add(client);
            client.start();
        }

        try {
            ss.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error Occured\n"
                    + "Message: Couldn't close Server Socket\n"
                    + "Cause: " + e.getMessage() + "\n");
        }

    }

    public static synchronized void broadcastMessage(String message) {
        Server s = getServerInstance();
        for (int i = 0; i < s.clients.size(); i++) {
            s.clients.get(i).writeMessage(message);
        }
    }

    private void establishConnection() {
        try {
            ss = new ServerSocket(4444);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error Occured\n"
                    + "Message: Couldn't establish server socket for connection\n"
                    + "Cause: " + e.getMessage() + "\n");
        }
        System.out.println("Server Socket has been created Successfully\n");
        isListening = true;
    }

    public static void removeClient(int id) {
        Server s = getServerInstance();
        for (int i = 0; i < s.clients.size(); i++) {
            if (id == s.clients.get(i).getId()) {
                s.clients.remove(i);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

### }

`ClientThread` class:

```
public class ClientThread extends Thread {

    private Socket socket;
    private BufferedReader reader;
    private PrintWriter writer;

    private int userId;
    private String userName;

    private boolean isConnected;

    public ClientThread(Socket socket, int id) {
        this.socket = socket;

        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            writer = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error Occured\n"
                    + "Message: Couldn't get socket's InputStream or OutputStream\n"
                    + "Cause: " + e.getMessage());
        }

        this.userId = id;

    }

    public void setUserName(String name) {
        this.userName = name;
    }

    public void setIsConnected(boolean flag) {
        isConnected = flag;
    }

    public BufferedReader getReader() {
        return reader;
    }

    public int getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        exchangeInformation();

        isConnected = true;
        String input;
        while (isConnected) {
            try {
                input = reader.readLine();
                if (input != null) {
                    if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("logout")) {
                        logout();
                    } else {
                        Server.broadcastMessage(input);
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Error Occured\n"
                        + "Message: Couldn't receive message from client\n"
                        + "Cause: " + e.getMessage() + "\n");
                isConnected = false;
            }

        }
    }

    public synchronized void writeMessage(String message) {
        writer.println(message);
    }

    public void writeMessage(int message) {
        writer.println(message);
    }

    private void logout() {
        setIsConnected(false);

        try {
            socket.close();
            reader.close();
            writer.close();
            System.out.println("User " + this.userId + " has loggedout"
            );
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error Occured\n"
                    + "Message: Couldn't close content(s)\n"
                    + "Cause: " + e.getMessage() + "\n");
        }
    }

    private void exchangeInformation() {

        try {
            String n = reader.readLine();
            setUserName(n);
            System.out.println("name has been received");
            writeMessage("Server: Welcome " + userName + "\n");

            writeMessage(userId);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error Occured\n"
                    + "Message: Couldn't receive client's name\n"
                    + "Cause: " + e.getMessage() + "\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you set the value of `userId` ?

Comment: @Berger It's an `int` variable generated by `Server` class passing to the constructor of client thread on server side

Comment: post the code as well as the code which calls it

Comment: @XtremeBaumer post what code? calls what?! `userId` ?

Comment: you say it is generated by the server. we need to know how and when it is generated. currently i don't see in your code, how you generate the id

Comment: Note that `writeMessage(String message)` shouldn't work with an `int` parameter.

Comment: @XtremeBaumer I send the code which generated id and pass it to the client

Comment: what is the methods name? or is it in a constructor?

Comment: @Berger There's another method which overloads the first one. It woks with `int` values

Comment: @XtremeBaumer what method's name? what is in a constructor? please be more specific.

Comment: the code which generates the IDs

Comment: @XtremeBaumer It is all in the EDIT code. the method is `generateId` and it is used in `ClientThread`'s constructor!

Comment: for the sake of all, just post all the code. i don't think you get what we need to know

Comment: @XtremeBaumer well the other parts of code works fine! i don't understand why i should send all the code. it's too much code! all code for generating id and send it to the clients is in codes I've sent

Comment: @XtremeBaumer Can you please explain exactly what you need?

Comment: but we can't see the chain which shows how it is created

Comment: you have these 2 lines `writeMessage("Server: Welcome " + userName + "\n");

            writeMessage(userId);`. right now, we have no indication how you "register" the users. also we don't see how/then you call the code you posted in the edit

Comment: @XtremeBaumer Look, in the code i sent after editing my post, I use `generateId` method to generate an id and send it to the `ClientThread`'s constructor. in `ClientThread` class, i send it to the `Client` class. which part of it is confusing?

Comment: when do you create a new `ClientThread`? what is the purpose of `ClientThread`?

Comment: @XtremeBaumer These two lines are after registering them! the registration process is in EDIT code. The request received by server and a thread would assign to it.

Comment: I guess you have 2/3 classes. just post them as whole. you dont get it at all. either you post them or you wont get help

Comment: @XtremeBaumer The `ClientThread` class is a thread which is assigned to a every client wants to connect to server. It is created in a loop in `Server` class after creating `ServerSocket` object and start listening for the requests.

Comment: @XtremeBaumer Now you have what you want. hope you can have any solution

Comment: That `\n` in your message adds an extra linebreak and thus an extra line, remove it.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel it worked! thanks a lot. But why it happens?! use `readLine` method. why it happens?! I used `\n` in all parts. but other parts work fine!!!

Comment: If you use `println`, then the writer itself already writes a linebreak (`\n`) after the provided text, so including one yourself makes it write **two** linebreaks, `readLine` simply reads until it encounters a linebreak. In other words, it stops at the linebreak you wrote, then the next `readLine` reads an empty line. The userid you expected to read is on the line **after** that.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Didn't know that. thanks so much. I used `\n` cause I wanted 2 line breakers. I think I should fine another way to do it. Thanks again.

Comment: If you wanted two linebreaks, you should also have been prepared to read those two linebreaks.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel can you post your answer so I can choose it as answer of this question?

Comment: No, I voted to close as 'caused by a typo'.